# Why does Hibernate log a different query that it does not actually execute?

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, log4j

I have a Hibernate query to retrieve a list of rows limited to a maximun number. But when I read the Hibernate logs, to my surprise, it filters internally a subquery that only has one row `select count(*)`

```sql
-- Log4j
-- INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: 
select *
from ( select count(*) as y0_
       from yyy this_
       where this_.type=3 and
                   this_.VALUE=2 and
                   this_.src='ZZZZZ'
     )
where rownum <= 100;
```

The outter criteria is like this:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
criteria.setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS); // MAX_RESULTS = 100

final List results = criteria.list(); // It executes the above query here.
```

What is the explanation to this behaviour? I have more queries with this misleading result on the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting a count projection. That makes hibernate return the count:

```
select count(*) from ...
```

Then you're telling Hibernate, although there is no way to get more than a single row for such a query, to limit the list of returned rows to maximum 100 rows. The correct way to do that using your database is to do what Hibernate does:

```
select * from ( <original query> ) where rownum <= 100;
```

If you don't want that useless wrapping query, then simply don't call the useless `setMaxResults(100)` method.

Comment: What I mean, is that the setMaxResulst actually filters the retrieved data by 100. It is neccessary. I do a inner query and it has for instance 1500 returned values, so I need the 100 filter, to not overload. It filters as intended. But on the other hand, Hibernate interprets the query differently, like if it has only 1 count(*). I will update the question  with the inner query. Thanks for your prompt answer.

Comment: A query doing select count(*), without any group by, can not return more than 1 row. It will never, ever, return 1500 rows.

Comment: I will extend the code, I may was understimating some code.

Comment: As I said in my answer, and as your question shows: `criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());`. That is what tells Hibernate that you want the query to count the rows that satisfy the criteria, i.e. execute a `select count(*)`. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html#rowCount--

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet. @Andreas shed light on it too. We where both right (I guess). Firstly there was a query to display a list of values (This query is not shown on logs. Why?. Whereas the projection above is used to set the a value to an object (This query is displayed on the log). As the method is named as listRetrieval, and the log only shows the unuseful query. I thought Hibernate was replacing the first query (not shown) for the unuseful one (misleading).

Comment: Side note. You realize that your query may not retrieve the same 100 rows each time

Comment: Yes, sometimes there are not that much, but it worth it for the cases where there are thousands of results. Thanks.